# Why restangular is giving an error although the request is successfull

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I am using Restangular to consume a REST API and it always gives me this error even though I can see the XHR request being made successfully on the developer console.

**Error**

```
{
  "data":null,
  "status":-1,
  "config":{
      "method":"GET",
      "transformRequest":[null],
      "transformResponse":[null],
      "jsonpCallbackParam":"callback",
      "headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"},
      "url":"http://localhost:8080/profile/v1/support/tickets"},
      "statusText":""
}
```

**Restangular API call**

```
angular.module('adf-widget-tickets-module-service',['restangular'])
  .service('ticketCRUDService', function ($rootScope, Restangular, $http) {
  Restangular.setBaseUrl('http://localhost:8080/profile/v1/support');
  this.readTickets = function () {
      Restangular.all('tickets').getList().then(function (response) {
          var test =  response.json;
          console.log(test);
          return test;
      },function (err) {
          console.error(JSON.stringify(err));
      },function () {
          console.log("loading......");
      })
  };
}
```

Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

**Update**

Here is the code for my REST endpoint

```
@GET
@Path("tickets")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response getAllTickets(){
    ArrayList<Ticket> allTickets = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        allTickets = elasticAPI.getAllTickets();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Response.ok(gson.toJson(allTickets), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why your endpoint is returning a `-1` status code?

Angular resolves only between: `200` and `299`

```
/*
* A response status code between 200 and 299 is considered a success status and will result in
* the success callback being called. Any response status code outside of that range is
* considered an error status and will result in the error callback being called.
* Also, status codes less than -1 are normalized to zero. -1 usually means the request was
* aborted, e.g. using a `config.timeout`.
* Note that if the response is a redirect, XMLHttpRequest will transparently follow it, meaning
* that the outcome (success or error) will be determined by the final response status code.
*/
```

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L457

Comment: It's weired. When I test the endpoint with a REST client it gives the response code 200. I can also see the request being made and getting a 200 response on the developer console. Could this be a CORS issue?

Answer (score 1):

As I guessed the problem was not on my client side code. It was because of that the request being rejected from the server due to CORS. Setting proper response headers for CORS support fixed the problem.